# Error when using power query to connect to API to powerBI

Tags: api, powerbi, powerquery

So I've been trying to connect to the API of our ATS system through PowerBI. The api uses an authorization header which I haven't been able to get working through power query. I've tried chatgpt (as does everyone these days) to help me solve the problem but it just sends me round in circles. Right now I'm getting the error:

"Expression.Error: The 'Authorization' header is only supported when connecting anonymously. These headers can be used with all authentication types: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cache-Control, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since, Prefer, Referer"

I have been able to connect to the API using code.

The API reads:

*To access the API, you will need a v3 API key. You can create an API key from the Administration settings page in CATS. Note that Transaction Codes for the previous version of the API will not work.
To authenticate, add an Authorization header to your requests that contains a value in the form Token .
Example header:
Authorization: Token*

I've written this in powerBI:

```
let
    GetJsonWithCustomHeaders = (url as text, optional headers as nullable record) as any =>
let
    DefaultHeaders = [
        #"Accept" = "application/json",
        #"Content-Type" = "application/json"
    ],
    Headers = if (headers <> null) then DefaultHeaders & headers else DefaultHeaders,
    JsonContent = Web.Contents(url, [Headers = Headers]),
    Result = Json.Document(JsonContent)
in
    Result,
    api_key = "My_Key",
    url = "https://api.catsone.nl/v3",
    endpoint = "/candidates", // Replace with the desired API endpoint, e.g., "/candidates" or "/jobs"
    AuthHeader = [#"Authorization" = "Token " & api_key],
    Source = GetJsonWithCustomHeaders(url & endpoint, AuthHeader),
    result = Source[result]
in
    result
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm no expert so it might be just me being stupid haha

Comment: Are you using anonymous authentication for the web data source in Data Source settings?  see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-data-source-settings-and-permissions-power-query-9f24a631-f7eb-4729-88dd-6a4921380ca9 to locate your settings